# xcode 5.0 undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 error and clang error

Tags: c++, xcode, macos

I recently upgraded to Xcode 5.0 and I am having problems with my command line C++ projects. Judging from answers on various forums, the problem lies with either my framework, or Xcode 5.0 not clearing out my "Library Search Paths" build setting.

When I do try clear out my library search path I find that it is empty. I have pasted my error below.

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:

```
"queueExam<int>::queueExam(int)", referenced from:
    _main in examMain.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: As per our discussion in the Apple Developer Forums; have you cleaned before building with the new compiler?  I doubt very much this relates to *Library Search Paths*.

Answer (score 0):

There can be two possibilities.
1. Either your constructor name queueExam::queueExam(int) has an error, i mean some spelling error.(As it says that the symbol is not defined)
2. Your program has compiled, but there is a problem while combining the .cpp files which you have created. (Linker Error)
So i suggest that you check on this.
If none of this work, try creating a new project and just copy paste the whole code into the new one.(This solves linker problems many times).

Comment: Tried all of those options and nothing seems to work. I also created a completely new project with different variables and I get the exact same error.

Comment: then its probably an internal error. If you have any previous version of Xcode or another mac, try on that!

Comment: I think the problem could be with using templates because without templates it works. Thanks for all the help :)